# $this->db->like not filtering results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a search form built in my website's header (I'm using Bootstrap as well). The purpose of the form is to query users, based on the input.

**View**

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" method="post" action="updates/search" name="search"> 
    <input type="text" class="input-medium" size="50" placeholder="Search for users" style="padding-left:10px">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small" name="sub">Search</button>
    </input>
</form>
```

**Model**

```
function get_search($input)
{
    $this->db->like('username',$input); 
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    print_r($query->result()); // for now i am just printing the results, in the future i will simply return this 
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index($renderData="")
{ 
    $this->load->model("user_model");
    $this->load->model("updates_model"); 

    $this->_render('pages/search');
}
```

When I run a search query, say "as;fa;sklfl;kasf", it still prints all of the usernames in the database (5), instead of a blank page. Is my get_search method not finding the $input variable for some reason?

**Edit: I fixed it. I had the value in the form, not in the input**

Comment: Add `echo $this->db->last_query();` to see the actual SQL query being ran.  That might help.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Okay.. So when I ran that, it gave SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `username` LIKE '%%'. So I guess that means my $input variable is not being passed correctly?

Comment: How does `get_search` get called?  How are you passing it the input?

Comment: I am calling it in the action, "updates/search." The method is $this->load->model("user_model"); $this->user_model->get_search($this->input->post('search'));

Comment: Your `<input>` doesn't have a name.  Try to move `name="search"` from the `<form>` to the `<input>`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat is right where is your name="search" ?

Answer (score 1):

your text box not given any name

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium" size="50" placeholder="Search for users" style="padding-left:10px" />
```

to

```
  <input type="text" name ="username" class="input-medium" size="50" placeholder="Search for users" style="padding-left:10px"/>
```

Then use your Query like-

```
$input = $this->input->post('username');
$this->db->like('username',$input); 
$query = $this->db->get('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->like('username',$input); 
$query = $this->db->get('users');
```

Where is the association of your like query with the variable $query?

You tell your framework to get all users and set it to $query.

```
$query = $this->db->get('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_search($input)
{
    //you might want to add `%` on your like statement just add both/after/before the third paraeter
    $this->db->like('username',$input,'BOTH'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    //check the query
    print_r($this->db->last_query());
}
```

Comment: `'both'` is the default, if you don't specify otherwise :)